# Validando evento com o operador `?`

Tags: c#

Estava implementando um método para lançar o evento `PropertyChanged` do `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Eu fiz a validação do evento de forma tradicional, ou seja, com `if (PropertyChanged != null)`. Porém o VS me sugeriu uma forma mais enxuta que é `PropertyChanged?.Invoke ( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs ( propertyName ) );`.

É óbvio que o código é autoexplicativo, ou seja, "Se `PropertyChanged` não for nulo, execute o método `Invoke`". Porém queria saber como se chama esse recurso para que eu possa pesquisar mais informações sobre ele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se chama "Null-Condicional operator". Mais informações aqui:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)